# Editing a dynamic property in a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, dynamic, propertygrid

I have a class that I want to be editable via a PropertyGrid. This class has some dynamic properties, as defined below;

```cs
public class Conditional
{
  public ConditionOperator Condition {get; set;}
  public bool CaseSensitive {get; set;}
  public dynamic Value1 {get; set;}
  public dynamic Value2 {get; set;}
  public List<dynamic> Values {get; set;}

  ...
}
```

`ConditionOperator` is an enum and works perfectly fine in the PropertyGrid, as does the bool, which is expected. The problem is `Value1`, `Value2` and `Values`. These are greyed out; uneditable.

Most of my searching has turned up things such as creating a custom `PropertyDescriptor` classes and the like. All of it seems quite excessive and not exactly what my situation requires.

Can anyone suggest how to go about enabling the property grid to allow me to edit the dynamic properties? (They will be either `string` or `double` if that helps at all).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

Couldn't you just make it a `List<object>` instead?

Comment: Nope, `Object` has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyGrid control was written before 'dynamic' typing was added to the .NET Framework and so it has no built-in idea how to handle that type.

You might be able to get around this by creating your own UITypeEditor that can provide the appropriate editing experience. I presume you would change how it is edited based on the type of value it is holding.